# Date of news is updated with text of news is corrected

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is admin panel where admin adds, edits or deletes news. Each news consist of "Title", "Body" and "Created". It's shown for site users.

However, there is a problem with date ("Created"). For example, news is created on 25 January, but admin edited it on 27 January. Аfter this it's shown as 27 January instead of 25 January - that isn't correct because it was created two days before.

I understand it's because when admin updates news and DateTime.Now function refreshes Created value. How can I remember time of creation "Post" in "Created"?

Post.cs

```
namespace Blog.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = "";
        public string Body { get; set; } = "";
        public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

PanelController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View(new PostViewModel());
    }
    else
    {
        var post = _repo.GetPost((int)id);
        return View(new PostViewModel
        {
            Id = post.Id,
            Title = post.Title,
            Body = post.Body
        });
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(PostViewModel vm)
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Id = vm.Id,
        Title = vm.Title,
        Body = vm.Body
    };
    if (post.Id > 0)
        _repo.UpdatePost(post);
    else
        _repo.AddPost(post);
    if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
        return View(post);
}
```

Comment: what's the _repo here?

Comment: In Edit you create a new `Post` object but you don't set the `Created` on it so it will be `DateTime.Now` and the DB will be updated. When you get an existing row you need to pass the date through to the view then back to the Edit, the same as you pass the Id through.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `IsModified` property during Update. Here the example

```
if (post.Id > 0)
{
    _repo.UpdatePost(post);
    _repo.Entry(post).Property(x => x.Created).IsModified = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways to archive this with your current model:

1.
You can either extend your `PostViewModel` by a `Created` property and set it accordingly in your GET request. After that you can access it again in the POST request and assign it to the newly created `Post` object. You'll have to add a hidden field for this property inside your `EditView` otherwise it will not be send back in your POST request.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View(new PostViewModel());
    }
    else
    {
        var post = _repo.GetPost((int)id);
        return View(new PostViewModel
        {
            Id = post.Id,
            Title = post.Title,
            Body = post.Body,
            Created = post.Created   // Remember the created date
        });
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(PostViewModel vm)
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Id = vm.Id,
        Title = vm.Title,
        Body = vm.Body,
        Created = vm.Created   // Re-Assign the created date
    };

    if (post.Id > 0)
        _repo.UpdatePost(post);
    else
        _repo.AddPost(post);

    if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
        return View(post);
}
```

2.
The other possibility would be to get the existing `Post` object in your `Edit` POST request and update the properties on the existing one:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(PostViewModel vm)
{
    var post = _repo.GetPost(vm.Id);

    if(post == null)
        post = new Post();

    post.Title = vm.Title;
    post.Body = vm.Body;

    if (post.Id > 0)
        _repo.UpdatePost(post);
    else
        _repo.AddPost(post);

    if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
        return View(post);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add another property if you want to remember both created and updated date.

Do not set Created to DateTime.Now, as this may override the actual date saved.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    public string Body { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Also, set these values when creating or updating a resource accordingly.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(PostViewModel vm)
{
    var post = new Post
    {
        Id = vm.Id,
        Title = vm.Title,
        Body = vm.Body
    };
    if (post.Id > 0)
    {
        post.Updated = DateTime.Now;
        _repo.UpdatePost(post);
    }

    else
    {
        post.Created = DateTime.Now;
        post.Updated = DateTime.Now; // If you want Created == Updated on creation
        _repo.AddPost(post);
    }

    if (await _repo.SaveChangesAsync())
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
        return View(post);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for feedback. I tried your option, but 1 January 0001 is shown now.

Comment: Are you saving Created and Updated your database (or whatever _repo is)?

Comment: @HashedPassword Your solution introduces the same bug as the solution of OP. You are creating a new `Post` object on POST without setting its `Created` property.